# Postgres weekly timetable

Tags: postgresql

I want to have a weekly `timetable` table in postgres, That stores availability time of a person in a week
Then I want to get a time range from a user and check that the person in available in that range or not

How can I do that in postgres , I know that Range type can help me, But I don't know how implement weekly tine table

```
timetable
╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ userId ║ day_of_week ║       during        ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║      1 ║           0 ║ [10:00:00 12:00:00] ║
║      1 ║           0 ║ [14:30:00 16:45:00] ║
║      1 ║           1 ║ [10:00:00 12:00:00] ║
║      1 ║           1 ║ [08:30:00 12:00:00] ║
║      1 ║           1 ║ [13:30:00 17:00:00] ║
║      1 ║           1 ║ [19:30:00 23:00:00] ║
║      1 ║           2 ║ [10:00:00 12:00:00] ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

day_of_week => The day of the week as Sunday(0) to Saturday(6)

I want to know , is user #1 available in a specific time range?

```
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-05-31 11:30) => true 
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-05-31 15:30) => false
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-06-02 00:00) => false
```

the timetable is just a sample , and You can offer better schema

A user can be available 24 hours, i.e in Sunday-Tuesday

```
timetable
╔════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ userId ║ day_of_week ║       during        ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║      2 ║           0 ║ [00:00:00 24:00:00] ║
║      2 ║           1 ║ [00:00:00 24:00:00] ║
║      2 ║           2 ║ [00:00:00 24:00:00] ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

So we have

```
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-05-31 11:30) => true 
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-05-31 15:30) => true 
(2020-05-31 11:00, 2020-06-02 00:00) => true 
(2020-06-02 00:00, 2020-06-03 01:00) => false
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added sample data

Comment: Is there any situation where an input range crossing more than one day would be valid?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, In my application input range can be 2 weeks

Comment: But that could only be valid if the timetable table contains time ranges from 00:00 to 24:00 for every day of the input range. Can you add an example where an input range over more then one day would be valid?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edit post and add mode details, A use can have a 7x24 timetable , and available for all time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can split up the input value (parameter) into each day, you can do something like this:

```
select bool_and(tt.user_id is not null)
from (
  values 
    (0, timerange('11:00', '24:00')),
    (1, timerange('00:00', '24:00'))
) as t(dow, day_range) 
  left join timetable tt 
         on tt.day_of_week = t.dow
        and tt.during @> t.day_range
        and tt.user_id = 2;
```

If you are limited by passing a timestamp range, you will need to turn the range into the corresponding number of days and time ranges per week day.

```
with parm (user_id, input) as (
  values 
    -- these are essentially your query parameters
    (2, tsrange('2020-05-31 11:00', '2020-06-02 00:00', '[)')) 
), days as (
  select user_id, 
         timerange(
         case 
           when g.day::date = lower(input)::date then lower(input)::time
           when g.day::date > lower(input)::date and g::date <= upper(input)::date then time '00:00'
         end,
         case 
           when g.day::date = upper(input)::date then upper(input)::time
           when g.day::date < upper(input)::date and g::date >= lower(input)::date then time '24:00'
         end, '()') day_range,
         extract(dow from g.day) as dow
  from parm
    cross join generate_series(lower(input)::date, upper(input)::date, interval '1 day') as g(day)
)
select d.day_range as input_range, 
       d.dow as input_dow, 
       tt.user_id, 
       tt.during, 
       tt.user_id is not null as is_match
from days d
  left join timetable tt
         on d.dow = tt.day_of_week
        and tt.during @> d.day_range
        and tt.user_id = d.user_id
```

Listing each column of the result is mainly there to show how it works. If you just need a true/false result, you can do `bool_and(tt_user_id is not null)` as I did in the first select. The first CTE (`with parm`)  can be removed if you replace the parameter in the second CTE directly.